# If else statement for jquery using selectors to see if a certain div has been appended to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Would this work if you had a div and you append one of these div to ? Such as

```
<div class ="append">
  <div id ="one"></div>
  <div id ="two"></div>
</div>
```

Then in `jQuery` do something like:

```
if ($(.append#one)) {do this}
else if ($(.append#two)){do this}
```

each of the div `#one` and `#two` have different numbers and that matters. So I was wondering if you could somehow do an if statement to check if a div has a another div with an id appended in it, if so you do the code else if its another div with another id do code.

Edit: The divs with the id one and two are not appended to div with class append at first, i have to pick either one or two to get appended to the div append. So can i check if the div .append has either div#one appended to it, if so do this, else if div#two appended to it do this

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you looking for `jQuery.has` or something ? I am unable to understand your question..

Comment: You'd have better to ask question regarding why would you need that. I guess you want to append div 1 or 2 depending if the `.append` div has one or the other or none. Providing a minimalistic sample would help for sure

Comment: I mean if i had an empty div with a class called append, and then as my program executes, either div#one or div#two will be appended in the div AT First, not both. But eventually all divs will be appended to it.  So then i was wondering if you do if .append has a div#one appended to ot do this, else if div#two do this

Comment: @henhen Please put the additional information in your question (not in a comment), i.e. edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if a div has a particular parent as well

```
if($( "#one" ).hasClass( "append" )){
  //do something
}else if($( "#two" ).hasClass( "append" )){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: Cool ty for tip

Comment: *"You could check if a div has a particular parent"* then doesn't show code to check parent...

Comment: Didn't get you mate? In this I'm just checking If the selector has a particular parent or not. if it does then we know this div is appended to the parent div.

Answer (score 1):

> check if a div has a another div with an id appended in it

You can use:

```
if ($(".append>[id]").length > 0)
```

or

```
if ($("div>div[id]").length > 0)
```

which will check return all items that are direct descendants of `.append` and have attribute `id`.

Comment: What does the .length > 0 do?

Comment: It checks if any items have been found.  The `$()` returns a "jquery array" of dom elements, so length tells you if there are any in that array.

Comment: What does the brackets [ ] and > mean?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like following.

```
if ($('.append #one').length) {
   // do this
}
else if ($('.append #two').length) {
   // do this
}
```

Comment: What does the .length do?

Comment: `length` returns the number of elements in the jQuery object. [See this](https://api.jquery.com/length/) @henhen

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(()=>{

  $('#div-one').click(()=>{
           $('#one').appendTo($('.append')); 
   });
  
  $('#check').click(()=>{
             if($('.append').children('#one').length!=0){
                 alert('one');
              } else{
                 alert('two');
              }
  });

});
```

```css
.append{color:Red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "append">append</div>
    <div id ="one">one</div>
    <div id ="two">two</div>
<br/>
<input type='button' id='div-one' value ='append one'/>
<input type='button' id='check' value='check'/>
```

Comment: Will look into this ty

Comment: `=>` is relatively new to javascript, so check if you need to support older browsers: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3D%3E